# What are the correct steps in solving polygon monotone triangulation?

Tags: computational-geometry, polygons

I am working out [image] step by step and I am stuck on vertex 7. I got that it was a regular vertex and helper(e_i-1) is not a merge vertex so I look for the leftmost edge in the sweep line. My question is, would e6 be considered to the left of it, or is it none? Any already completed examples that I could see would help me understand this greatly.

Comment: I suspect you're going to need to give us more context, for us to help you.  It sounds like you're working with a particular algorithm.  Can you describe the algorithm, and what prevents you from executing it by hand?  What is "helper"?  What is a merge vertex?  The more self-contained you can make the question, the more likely that someone will be able to help.

Comment: I'm doing monotone polygon triangulation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation. The algorithm is from http://www.cs.uu.nl/geobook/. I visualize helper as a dictionary. I don't know if I'm allowed to link pdf's here so I'm not sure I can show you the algorithm. I just want to double-check my work.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include information in the question itself, rather than in the comments, so people don't have to read the comments to understand your question, and so it reads well for someone who encounters this for the first time.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others in the future.  If you can make the question useful and interesting for others, it might be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: You can link to the PDF (many folks frown on linking to illegal copies of copyrighted books, but that doesn't seem to be the case here), but it'd also be useful to provide a self-contained summary of the algorithm and of what is helper and how it used.

Comment: @Tigertron It may also be a good idea to mention that the particular algorithm you're executing is a sweepline algorithm to partition the polygon into monotone pieces. (this is a step of the triangulation algorithm, the idea is that triangulating monotone polygons is relatively simple) The example is also taken from the same book (section 3.2).